# How to declare a deferred variable that is computed only once for all?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a shell program that takes ages to complete. As written, executing `make build` takes 4 x 2 seconds to complete because `$(value)` is computed for each file.

A solution is to declare `value` a `deferred` variable by using `:=` instead of `=`.

Unfortunately this is not a solution either because it slows down the execution of `make clean` and any other targets by 2 seconds because `value` is computed for nothing.

```
value = $(shell sleep 2 && echo 42)

in = a b c d
out = $(addsuffix .out,$(in))

build: $(out)

%.out: %
    echo $(value) > $< || [ rm $@ -a true ]

init:
    touch $(in)

clean:
    rm -vf $(out)
```

How can I set a variable what is assigned only if used, but only computed once ?

Said differently, I would like `build` to take 2 seconds to complete and `clean` to be immediate.

I am not interested to a solution that involves conditionals in order to bypass the assignment of `value` if the target is not `build`.

An alternative solution would be this. Unfortunately in this case I need to check whether or not the `shelve` file needs to be regenerated.

```
value = $(cat shelve)

shelve: 
    sleep 2 && echo 42 > $@ || [ rm $@ -a true ]

in = a b c d
out = $(addsuffix .out,$(in))

build: $(out)

%.out: %
    echo $(value) > $< || [ rm $@ -a true ]

init:
    touch $(in)

clean:
    rm -vf $(out)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a trick you can play:

```
value = $(eval value := $(shell cat shelve))$(value)
```

How this works: `value` is first assigned using recursive assignment so the value on the RHS is not expanded.

The first time `value` is expanded the make parser will first run the `$(eval ...)` which starts up a "new parser" for makefiles.  In that parser, the content `value := $(cat shelve)` is evaluated.  Here, `value` is a simple variable assignment so the RHS is expanded immediately and the `$(shell ...)` is run and assigned to `value`.

Remember make doesn't really have a concept of variable scope, so this `value` is just the same global `value` variable that we are setting in the outer parser.

Then the eval completes and expands to the empty string, and make continues parsing things.  Here it finds the value `$(value)` and expands that... `value` now has the result from the eval, not the eval text itself, so that's what will be expanded.

Maybe this will help:

```
value = $(eval value := $(shell cat shelve))$(value)
```

Here `value` contains the string `$(eval value := $(shell cat shelve))$(value)`

Now you expand it:

```
%.out: %
        echo $(value) > $< ...
```

Make starts to expand this recipe.  It gets to `$(value)` and sees it needs to expand the variable `value`: since it's recursive it expands the value:

```
$(eval value := $(shell cat shelve))$(value)
```

First it expands the `eval`, which parses this:

```
value := $(shell cat shelve)
```

That sets the `value` variable as a simply-expanded variable, so the RHS is expanded immediately.  Say the results of `cat shelve` are "foo", so `value` is now set to `foo` (and it's marked simply expanded).

That's the end of the eval, so then make starts the next part which is `$(value)`, so it looks up the variable `value` and discovers it's a simply-expanded variable with the value `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to turn that value into a regular file target that gets updated only when its prerequisites change. If you insist on rebuilding that target for every build, mark it as phony.

When `clean` target does not depend on that file, then it won't be rebuilt when you invoke `make clean`.

---

In

```
%.out: %
    echo $(value) > $< || [ rm $@ -a true ]
```

`echo $(value) > $<` updates the prerequisite, whereas `make` expects it to update the target only. Updating a prerequisite must be done by a separate rule with that prerequisite being the target.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the assignment depend on the target name in `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`:

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
   value := $(shell sleep 2 && echo 42)
endif
```

See also [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals) for details.

Comment: @nowox Sorry, I jumped the gun. Why would you reject a working solution to the problem? Maybe if you expanded on the reasons we can find a good solution. This might be an X-Y-Problem.

Comment: The reason is that I have dozens of targets, some that depends on some `slow` variables and some not. Using conditionals make the Makefile hard to read and much more complex that it should be.

Comment: @nowox Hmm. Then my approach would likely be some out-of-the-box thinking: how to make the slow variables fast by determining and removing their dependencies and attempt to cache the result.

Comment: Right, this is something that I am struggling with. Actually my issue is that this variable takes its value from a Python script that extract and validate a piece of information from a serialized file. The process is quite fast, but the startup of Python takes already 800 ms on Cygwin. I can make my script much more complex by using persistent cache (which is hard to code properly).